# Duplicity without encryption

Tags: backup, encryption, gnupg, duplicity

I tried using duplicity without encryption using `--no-encryption` flag, and although the data is stored and not encrypted, I am not able to restore it using `duplicity restore --file-to-restore` option (I receive error that `test_file.txt not found in archive - no files restored.`). If I try to list files from my archive I also get `gpg: decryption failed: secret key not available`.

Obviously, as the error says, I've not setup GPG keys on my Ubuntu. Is there a way to use `duplicity` without any kind of encryption and without GPG? I know that duplicity encrypts **and** signs a backup, but how can I disable signing of a backup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try following.

Create Backup

```
duplicity _data_to_be_backed_up_ file://_path_to_backup_ --no-encryption
```

Restore Backup

```
duplicity restore file://_path_to_backup_ _restore_path_ --no-encryption
```